# Is it possible to install a helm chart with a custom value not found in the templates or values.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to install a helm chart with a key/value that is not present in one of the templates and I prefer not to edit the already existing templates.

In particular, I need to change `resources.limits.cpu` and `resources.limits.memory` in `k8s-job-template.yaml` but `resources` is not even mentioned in that file.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I found a solution to this.

Simply download the chart using the following command:

```
helm fetch <chart> --untar --destination /local/path/to/chart
```

Go to the folder `/local/path/to/chart/<chartname>` and make the desired changes.

After this, simply install the helm chart based on the locally edited chart:

```
helm install  /local/path/to/chart/<chartname>
```

Answer (score 4):

The only customizations it's possible to make for a Helm chart are those the chart author has written in; you can't make arbitrary additional changes to the YAML files.

([Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) allows merges of arbitrary YAML content and is built into recent `kubectl`, but it doesn't have some of the lifecycle or advanced templating features of Helm.)